# Django: Bypass form validation?

Tags: django, django-forms

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760793/bypass-django-form-validation-on-new-form-instance), but the solution there won't work for me.

Basically, I'm trying to do this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    profile_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST)
    # ...
else:
    profile_form = UserProfileForm(request.GET)
```

But then the form gets validated on a GET. Using `initial=request.GET` instead doesn't work either because each of the entries is a list rather than  a string. i.e., if I try to go to `myform?company=mycompany` the `mycompany` field gets set to `[u'mycompany']`.

Is there a different way to bypass validation, or is there an easy way to convert a `querydict` into regular dict (without the lists)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could turn `request.GET` into a dictionary with values that aren't lists like so:

```
initial = dict(map(lambda x:(x[0], x[1][0]), dict(request.GET).items()))
profile_form = UserProfileForm(initial=initial)
```

That will grab the first item in each list, which means it will only work if all your inputs have different names (which they should or you're not doing something right). Let me know if it works.

You may not need the `dict(request.GET).items()`, you may be able to just put `request.GET.items()`.

Comment: Hah! It worked, but then tried just `request.GET.items()` and instead it gave me only the first letter of each item, which suggested that they weren't lists anymore, but strings. Turns out `initial=request.GET.items()` works as is.

Answer (score 1):

Bah... Bryce's solution won't work if the form has a prefix on it either. We have to trim it off:

```
def initdict(querydict, prefix=None):
    if prefix is None:
        return querydict.items()
    p = prefix + '-'
    l = len(p)
    return dict((k[l:],v) for k,v in querydict.iteritems() if k.startswith(p))
```

Usage:

```
profile_form = UserProfileForm(prefix='profile', initial=initdict(request.GET, prefix='profile'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Although it seems that you have already found a solution, why not use a form class which inherits from UserProfileForm, like NoValidationUserProfileForm? In that case you can loop over all fields to set `required = False`.

```
class NoValidationUserProfileForm(UserProfileForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NoValidationUserProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['myfield'].required = False
```

Comment: You can has a +1, but that seems like a much bigger hackjob.

Comment: I'd disagree. I think it's a lot more readable. Overriding __init__() doesn't necessarily a hack make.

Comment: No... not the overriding `__init__`, but requiring a 2nd version of every form, and disabling the `required` just to avoid displaying some error messages.